# Jenkins - How to trigger QA tests job build by changes on another git project

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, visual-studio-app-center

I know this is a frequent topic, but I couldn't find a straight-forward answer for my case. I just started with Jenkins, so I need help to achieve the setup described below.

**I have:**

- One maven job that is sourced from GIT repo and is executing my QA tests. (let's call it #QAjob)
- then...
- One project on BITBUCKET which is the website project (#WEBproject)
- Another Android/IOS project that is being built on the APP CENTER (#MOBILEproject)

**I want to achieve the following behavior on Jenkins:**

- When somebody pushed to BITBUCKET #WEBproject on the STAGING branch - I want to start #QAjob
- When somebody's started build on APP CENTER **has completed** on STAGING branch - I want to start #QAjob

I've set up my #QAjob, it pulls my tests code from GIT and executes the tests correctly. So I just need to set up these triggers when the job will get executed. I figured out that there are webhooks on BITBUCKET and APP CENTER that can ping a job when the push was done, but I don't know how to use it to accomplish the described setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer by myself and would like to share it in case somebody else got stuck with a similar case.

Solution is Jenkins plugin - [generic-webhook-trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/)

Detailed instructions can be found here - [Jenkins – How to build a specific branch on Bitbucket](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch-on-bitbucket/)

Instructions for BitBucket can be used for AppCenter as well, there are just differences in JSON path expressions for variables.

If somebody needs help, feel free to add a comment.